# best way to copy TCHAR pointer to TCHAR pointer

Tags: c++

I dont know why this seems to be more complicated than what it is! I simply want to replace the contents of `str2` with the contents of `str`, they are both are strings. This seems to work but I am not sure this is the right way of doing it...I am using Visual Studio 2008.

EDIT: I have to use `new` for `str2`

```
TCHAR *str = _T("Hello");
TCHAR* str2;
str2 = new TCHAR[23];   // let us say this is big enough 
str2 = _T("ok");
memcpy( &str2, &str, (_tcslen(str)+1)*sizeof(TCHAR));
```

EDIT2: I tried this as Michael suggested but I got `access violation error` :(

```
TCHAR *str = _T("Hello");
    TCHAR* str2;
    str2 = new TCHAR[23];   // let us say this is big enough 
    str2 = _T("ok");
    _tcscpy( str2, str);
```

Comment: `sizeof(str)` is the size of its pointer. Use `strlen(str)+1`.

Comment: in Windows land you have a whole stack of wide char copy routines. [Take a look](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/td1esda9.aspx)

Comment: Following @DietmarKühl you have also discarded the pointer returned by `new` and so you have  a memory leak, because you can't now `delete` it.

Comment: More important, Why `new` it in the first place?

Comment: @WeatherVane I am deleting the pointer at the end of the program, this is just a snippet

Comment: @DietmarKühl will work if I change sizeof() to (_tcslen(str)+1)*sizeof(TCHAR)

Comment: You cant, you replaced it with `str2 = _T("ok");` so it's gone.

Comment: Then you're deleting the wrong one and trying to delete a const. That's not going to go over well at runtime.

Comment: So do I get this isn't the code you are using?

Comment: Just go with `TCHAR str2[23]` save you a lot of trouble.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie well-taken point

Comment: @Ditmar: I suspect the OP wants to 'set' the new-ed string to "ok"...

Comment: @Tive you are right!

Comment: @Samer No, the code is not OK. Several flaws and errors as mentioned.

Comment: @Samer - The `new` returns a pointer *value*.  Note the emphasis on *value*.  So when you call `delete []`, you must use the same *value* that was returned, not necessarily the same pointer.  So if `new` returned (for arguments sake) `0x234B3210`, then by hook or by crook, `delete` better be getting `0x234B3210`.  So saying you're deleting the same pointer at the end really means nothing.

Comment: @samer: I think you really need to realize what you're doing: both str and str2 are already pointers, so you don't have to do an address-of against them in the memcpy call.  Second, to set individual elements of str2, for example tto o, k, and char-null, you'd do: str2[0] = _T('O'); str2[1]=_T('k'); str2[2] = _T('\0'); ...  Also when using memcpy you need to be sure that the source and destination addresses don't overlap...

Comment: Use `std::string`, std::wstring`, or `std::basic_string<>` for strings and `std::vector` if it's just a raw buffer. No need to use raw pointers, naked arrays, `new` or `delete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
TCHAR *str = _T("Hello");
```

OK.

```
TCHAR* str2;
```

OK.

```
str2 = new TCHAR[23];   // let us say this is big enough
```

Ok, but must be paired with `delete[]`.

```
str2 = _T("ok");
```

Not Ok. Overwrite of pointer to `new TCHAR[23];` That memory is for all intents and purposes gone and unrecoverable.

```
memcpy( &str2, &str, (_tcslen(str)+1)*sizeof(TCHAR));
```

Not OK. str and str2 are already pointers, so taking their addresses with `&` points you at the wrong spot in memory.

My cut of the above:

```
#include "windows.h"
#include "TCHAR.H" // for _tcscpy_s

int main()
{
    TCHAR * str = _T("Hello");
    TCHAR * str2 = new TCHAR[23];
    _tcscpy_s(str2, 23, _T("OK")); // store OK

    _tcscpy_s(str2, 23, str); // Copy str   
    delete[] str2;
}
```

Which is pretty much the same as what Michael Burr suggested. The only significant differences are preserving the OK and `_tcscpy_s` which limits the copy to 23 characters by terminating the program on overrun if I remember correctly. [wcsncpy_s](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5dae5d43.aspx) will allow truncation if termination is not your answer. Don't know if there is an _t version of it.

The C++ way would be

```
std::wstring str(L"Hello");
std::wstring str2(L"OK");
str2 = str; // for the copy.
str2.c_str() // to get a c style string
```

Edit: Need to make an extra note here. The C++ way isn't quite the same as TCHAR functions. TCHAR transparently switches between character types depending on the options set during compilation so that the same source could be built for systems with or without wide character support. wstring is strictly wide. The L-prefixed strings are strictly wide. You can do the same thing with macros wrapping all of the strings and streams, but it won't be trivial and eeewwwwww.... Macros...

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use `TCHAR` (which I'm not sure I'd recommend), look in `tchar.h` for the macros that give you `TCHAR` equivalents for all the `strxxx()` functions.  For example, to copy `TCHAR`-based strings you can use `_tcscpy()`.

Actually, there are macros for `TCHAR` variants for many of the basic runtime library functions that take a string or char argument, not just the `strxxx()` set of functions.

So your example could boil down to:

```
TCHAR *str = _T("Hello");
TCHAR* str2 = new TCHAR[23];   // let us say this is big enough 
_tcscpy( str2, str);
```

Comment: Thanks @Michael, is it safe to delete str2 afterwards?

Comment: @Samer: `_tcscpy()` is just `strcpy()` or `wcscpy()` depending on what a `TCHAR` is. So it has the same effect on object lifetime management as those functions would (that is: no effect)..